# Perforce depot/client mapping

Tags: mapping, client, perforce, depot

Is there command in Perforce to get information which clients has mapping for particular folder from depot ?

Example:

I have depot location //depot/myfolder/somefile.java

I want to know information which clients map this location to which path:

//client1/c:/folder1/somefile.java
//client2/d:/folder2/somefile.java
...

I can get this information from "p4 client" but it is for current client and not for particular folder/file.

Regards, Victor

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with a small script using the p4 clients command to list clients:

```
p4 help clients

clients -- Display list of clients
workspaces -- synonym for 'clients'

p4 clients [-u user] [-e nameFilter -m max]

Lists all client workspaces currently defined in the server.

The -u user flag lists client workspaces that are owned by the
specified user.

The -e nameFilter flag lists workspaces with a name that matches
the nameFilter pattern, for example:  -e 'svr-dev-rel*'

The -m max flag limits output to the specified number of workspaces.
```

and then iterate over each client using

```
p4 client -o <client name>
```

to list the client spec, and finally search for the path(s) you are interested in.